# Is it advisable to install firebase tools in my pc universally?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I was facing this issue: flutterfire:

> The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
> was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I searched for it and got to know i have to set firebase environment

I did it globally not inside the project will it harm me in my future projects by conflicting it or it's just fine.

Any suggestion or answer might help. If you have done it locally for each project kindly provide me the reason for doing so and else it's fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You don't have to *set firebase environment*. You have to add the folder to your system PATH. If you don't want to do that, you're going to have to manually type that full path repeatedly, which is going to be annoying, time-consuming, and prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely install it globally, there will be no conflicts between projects. You will need to launch `flutterfire configure` for each project individually though.